# Can OpenGeo Suite be deployed in production environment (using WAR package) for free?

Tags: boundless-suite, license

Is there a possibility to use OpenGeo Suite in production environment (using the WAR package) for free? 
Actually we are planning to deploy on a glassfish (alternatively Tomcat) container openGeo Suite. In a first step we think we can manage to set everything ourselves, thus we don´t need any support of OpenGeo. The pricing for the WAR package with glassfish costs 45000$ and what I understood it is only for the support. Can we get the WAR package for free if we don´t need any Support?

Comment: Yes, but it depends on what your "production environment" needs are. Look at http://opengeo.org/products/suite/pricing/ and if the "community" column (which basically means - no support) meets your needs, then use that. If not, you'll need a support agreement from someone. If we're not answering the question, please try to edit it (just click edit above) to explain what you really want to know. Some detail might help - what you are worried about, the nature of your production deployment, what you've tried in staging, and what the remaining issues are.

Comment: When I said "click edit above", I meant it. Please fix your question - this isn't a chat site, its a Q&A site.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you may deploy the Production WAR version of OpenGeo Suite (or any other version) in production free of charge. The pricing on the website refers only to maintenance contracts that include support.

Here's the new link to OpenGeo Suite and its pricing:

http://boundlessgeo.com/solutions/opengeo-suite/

Hope this helps.